# How to access a field in a related django model other than the primary key

Tags: class, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

This seems a silly, simple question. I'm going round in circles trying to get this work, but I can't see the wood for the trees.

Given a simple model such as (I've skipped the imports):

```
class Location(models.Model):
    description = model.CharField(max_length=40)
    address1 = model.CharField(max_length=40)
    # ..... (and so on)
    tel = model.CharField(max_length=12)
```

and another with a relationship to it:

```
class InformationRequest(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    request_date = Models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    # ..... (and so on)
```

How do I add a field that references the 'tel' field from the Location model in such a way that it can be populated automatically or from a select list in Django admin.

Comment: So, do you want to _access_ or _add_ a field?

Comment: If you want to _access_ the `tel` field from `InformationRequest` instance you simply do it like this: `instance.source.tel`. Other than that, I'm not sure what the question is, sorry :)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear.

How do I add the attribute to the InformationRequest model (e.g. in the form 'contact_tel = models.ForeignKey(....)') such that the value stored in the Location.tel field populates the InformationRequest.contact_tel field with the value appropriate for the linked record. That is if Location.tel = '123' for id/pk = '1', the InformationRequest.contact_tel is the same for the record where InformationRequest.source = '1'.

Apologies, not sure how I can explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if I get this right than you are, nomen est omen, thoroughly confusing the way that relational databases work :] One of key principles is to eliminate redundancy. There shouldn't be the very same piece of data stored in two tables that are related to one another.

I think that your current models are correct. Given these instances (I'm ignoring the fact that you have other, non-nullable fields)...

```
>>> loc = Location()
>>> loc.tel = "123"
>>> loc.save()
>>> info = InformationRequest()
>>> info.source = loc
>>> info.save()
```

...you can access `tel` from `InformationRequest` instance just like this:

```
>>> info.source.tel
'123'
```

You can also create a method...

```
class InformationRequest(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name="information_requests")
    request_date = Models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    # ..... (and so on)

    def contact_tel(self):
        return self.source.tel
```

... and get it like this:

```
>>> info.contact_tel()
'123'
```

You can even trick it into being an attribute...

```
class InformationRequest(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name="information_requests")
    request_date = Models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    # ..... (and so on)

    @property
    def contact_tel(self):
        return self.source.tel
```

... and get it without parentheses:

```
>>> info.contact_tel
'123'
```

Anyway, you should work your way around it programatically. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you've sussed what I was trying to do.

I take your point about the redundancy bit but I was trying to going through a thought exercise (and the models are a simplfied version of a something I was looking at) and couldn't for the life of me how to get that one out even though I've seen the solution before... So frustrating!!!

I will try to replicate your solution later. Very many thanks for putting me back on the right path.

Comment: In essence your solution worked although there is one fly in the ointment, so to speak. If I can ask a supplementary question: the 'contact_tel' property of the InformationRequest model can be seen in the list_display of the ModelAdmin, but Django throws a 'field not found' error if I try to add it to the list of the fields in a fieldset - what else am I missing??

Comment: The catch is that you cannot edit the `contact_tel` as it is not a field (as in column in a database). `list_display` is fine because it just displays things but fieldsets house actual model fields that can be edited. If you want to display (and edit) the fields from related model you need to look into the concept of Inlines. Dig in here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin

Comment: pythonsvili - Many thanks - Appreciate the time you've taken.